# Regex in .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my url for a project I'm currently working on.
The regex I have is working in my test strings but not when I put it in the .htaccess.

What I'm trying to do is make this url:

```
http://project.localhost/abcd/index.php?test=test123
```

Rewrite to:

```
http://project.localhost/index.php?id=abcd&test=test123
```

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /\/(.*?)\//g /index.php?id=$2 [QSA]
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the ?test= will not always be the same. It can have multiple, different parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a much more simple regex

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Note the `[QSA]` appends the other paramters in the query string.

Edit: Added condition for files

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to be doing something in the online tester [link](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) I use but not in my actual htaccess file (I have to save it as .htaccess in my project.localhost directory, right?). The result from the test is that the end url is "The new url is http://project.localhost/index.php?id=abcd/index.php"

Comment: Thanks, this almost works! Instead of only the id, I get this: [id] => 123-test/index.php. I'm thinking this is an issue in the regex?

Comment: Actually i didn't the `index.php` in the original URL. Can you leave that out? It works without `index.php`.

Comment: Alright awesome, that works, thanks. How would it look like if for example the file wouldn't be index.php but log.php?

Comment: As I understand, it is the idea not to have any `.php` file in a clean URL. But of course you can also rewrite to any other (existing) php file.

Comment: Upvoted for the simpler, cleaner and more concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is unable to understand the pattern of your rule, that is why it's not being processed.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/index.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?id=%1&%2=%3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately no luck yet, I tried it in my htaccess file and also in an online htaccess tester.

Also, I forgot the mention in my original question that the url doesn't always have ?test=, it can also be another value, sometimes multiple as well. I'll edit my question. Apologies!

Comment: Sorry that I didn't reply to this yet, testing many different things. This is now throwing an Internal Server Issue. The online tester states the following: 

    Debugging info:
    1  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/index.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+)  [NC]  This condition was not met.
    2  RewriteRule ^ /index.php?id=%1&%2=%3 [NC,L]  This rule was not met.

Comment: @Levi the rule is ok, works fine on my apache server. /foo/index.php?test=123 is successfully rewriting to /index.php?id=foo&test=123. i think your other rules are conflicting with this or may be you are going to a wrong url.

Comment: Online tester is not 100% accurate, so you should not rely on that.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't know which other rules they would be. My htaccess file does not contain anything else and the url is exactly what I pasted here.